# calculating difference between array values php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this small section of code.

```
<?php foreach($last_activity as $activity) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $activity['category'];?></td>
    <td><?= $activity['activity'];?></td>
    <td><?= $activity['datetime'];?></td>
    <td><?= $activity[''];?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This runs a loop populating table rows with data from query. 
What I want to be able to do providing possible this way...is in the final column in the row is calculate the difference between the datetime column in its present row with that of the row above.

is this possible (e.g by putting a snippet of php script in my final `<td>` column?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it can be done with something like this:

```
<?php $recent_datetime = null;
      foreach($last_activity as $activity): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$activity['category'];?></td>
    <td><?=$activity['activity'];?></td>
    <td><?=$activity['datetime'];?></td>
    <td><?= ($recent_datetime 
              ? $activity['datetime'] - $recent_datetime 
              : $activity['datetime'] );
         ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $recent_datetime = $activity['datetime']; endforeach; ?>
```